# running cron once a minute 8am-8pm

Tags: cron, time

i need to run cron job once a minute 8a.m. - 8p.m.

my code is: `*/01 8-20 * * * user /usr/bin/php -f script.php > /dev/null`

but it seems to fail..

Comment: You don't need the `/01` part. The `*` denotes that it will run every minute.

Comment: indeed! but if the interval would be 5 mins - then `*/05 8-20 * * *`, correct? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The correct line would be

```
* 8-20 * * * user /usr/bin/php -f script.php > /dev/null
```

Comment: indeed! but if the interval would be 5 mins - then `*/05 8-20 * * *`, correct?

Comment: yes, for every five minutes you would use */5, you do not need the leading zero.

Comment: do you need more information on this topic or do you have any other reason not to accept this answer?